# Desktop Browser notification, global listener

Tags: javascript

I want to set a listner to catch information created by desktop push notification from any site in chrome.


Catch all notifications created on my browser from all opened sites

for example:
- open this link in chrome:
   https://davidwalsh.name/demo/notifications-api.php

- click "Show a Notification"


I want to catch that notification information and display it in my app.

This is just an example.

Is there a way that I can catch notification and use its title and body text to filter out something in my App?

Comment: Aren't notifications sandboxed? I don't think you are allowed to access other sites notifications. Huge privacy concerns around that...

Comment: I want to use notifications that are displaying on my local browser.

Comment: I don't think you understand. Based on your question, you are asking how you can access browser notifications that other sites created/sent. That is a massive security and privacy concern, and therefor is not allowed.

Comment: I don't think that would be a security and privacy concern to make listener to those notifications which are displaying on my pc locally. If you notice, windows notification bar also have a global listener to listen and display notification message and tittle. You might be right, but as in android development we can create a global listener to listen to those which are send to our device. If some information is displaying on my pc, I don't think using that information would be a security issue. but appreciate your answer.

Comment: You don't think being able to see notifications from other websites that they create/send is a privacy concern? I mean of course Android supports it since Android has 0 sense of privacy at all. But just look at iOS. Reading other apps push notifications would NEVER be allowed. Just imagine someone sends you a message, and having other apps be allowed to read that. Huge privacy concerns with that. I didn't give access for other apps to be able to read my notifications. So why should they be allowed to?

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are sandboxed, which means you are limited in access to them. Browsers don't give you access to see or access notifications created/sent by other websites. You are limited to the API specification for your site only.

It would create massive privacy and security concerns if you were allowed to see all browser notifications from all sites for a user.